# Energy of a molecule using MOs diagram (case of CH4)

Tags: quantum-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory, energy

I'm trying to find the ground state energy of CH4 in order to compare it with simulations I made. I came across this diagram of energy (not sure it gives the true energies though, if you could confirm...) and I wanted to know whether if to determine the ground state energy, we simply have to add up the energy of each MOs for each electron ? Here for instance we'd have E(ground) = (-2 x 25.7 - 6 x 14.8) eV ?

Thank you for your answer!

[image]

Comment: See https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/164470/5017

Comment: Note also that your MO diagram here also ignores the $1s$ electrons from the carbon atom, so you cannot easily compare with a quantum calculation that uses all electrons.